# Slidetoggle div only after previous element has close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I currently have the follow set up:  (all divs with a class of "secret" are hidden)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="block align">
        <a class="desktop" data-toggle-target="click-1">
        </a>
    <div>
    <div class="block align">
        <a class="desktop" data-toggle-target="click-2">
        </a>
    <div>
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="click-1" class="secret">
        stuff
    <div>
    <div id="click-2" class="secret">
        stuff
    <div>
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="block align">
        <a class="desktop" data-toggle-target="click-3">
        </a>
    <div>
    <div class="block align">
        <a class="desktop" data-toggle-target="click-4">
        </a>
    <div>
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="click-3" class="secret">
        stuff
    <div>
    <div id="click-4" class="secret">
        stuff
    <div>
<div>
```

I slideToggle one a time with the following

```
$('.align .desktop').click(function (e) {
    $( '#' + $(this).data('toggleTarget') ).slideToggle(300).toggleClass('open');        
});
```

The problem is, if I click on data-toggle-target="click-2" to open the corresponding div, i need any other divs that are open to close first, then have the corresponding div slideToggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML structure is not ideal for this type of thing but chaining together a series of selectors can accomplish this:

```
$('.align .desktop').click(function (e) {
   var target = $(this).data('toggleTarget');
   $( '#' + target).siblings(".secret").slideUp().end().closest(".row").siblings(".row").find(".secret").slideUp().end().end().end().slideToggle(300).toggleClass('open');        
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x81jkspq/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Since you use JQuery use their BuildIn Function for an Accordion
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

UPDATE:
Or for your Structur write a function that closes all Blocks first and than opens the Clicked one.

Comment: @j-s-stack how would you use accordion with this layout?  Not sure how i would define selectors

Comment: Then use just .slideToggle without .toggleClass - But that doesnt Close the other divs